# R Recode variable for all observations that do not occur more than once

Tags: r, recode

I have a simple dataframe that looks like the following:

```
Observation X1 X2 Group
1           2   4   1
2           6   3   2
3           8   4   2
4           1   3   3
5           2   8   4
6           7   5   5
7           2   4   5
```

How can I recode the `group` variable such that all non-recurrent observations are recoded as "unaffiliated"?

The desired output would be the following:

```
Observation X1 X2 Group
1           2   4   Unaffiliated
2           6   3   2
3           8   4   2
4           1   3   Unaffiliated
5           2   8   Unaffiliated
6           7   5   5
7           2   4   5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be first grouping then checking for maximum of row number and finishing with an `ifelse`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(Group = ifelse(max(row_number()) == 1, "Unaffiliated", as.character(Group))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

```
  Observation    X1    X2 Group       
        <int> <int> <int> <chr>       
1           1     2     4 Unaffiliated
2           2     6     3 2           
3           3     8     4 2           
4           4     1     3 Unaffiliated
5           5     2     8 Unaffiliated
6           6     7     5 5           
7           7     2     4 5
```

Answer (score 5):

We may use `duplicated` to create a logical vector for non-duplicates and assign the 'Group' to `Unaffiliated` for those non-duplicates

```
df1$Group[with(df1, !(duplicated(Group)|duplicated(Group, 
     fromLast = TRUE)))] <- "Unaffiliated"
```

-output

```
> df1
  Observation X1 X2        Group
1           1  2  4 Unaffiliated
2           2  6  3            2
3           3  8  4            2
4           4  1  3 Unaffiliated
5           5  2  8 Unaffiliated
6           6  7  5            5
7           7  2  4            5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Observation = 1:7, X1 = c(2L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 
7L, 2L), X2 = c(4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 4L), Group = c(1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `!` and `|`?

Answer (score 3):

`unfaffil` takes a vector of Group numbers and returns `"Unaffiliated"` if it has one element and otherwise returns the input.  We can then apply it by Group using `ave`. This does not overwrite the input. No packages are used but if you use dplyr then `transform` can be replaced with `mutate`.

```
unaffil <- function(x) if (length(x) == 1) "Unaffiliated" else x
transform(dat, Group = ave(Group, Group, FUN = unaffil))
```

giving

```
  Observation X1 X2        Group
1           1  2  4 Unaffiliated
2           2  6  3            2
3           3  8  4            2
4           4  1  3 Unaffiliated
5           5  2  8 Unaffiliated
6           6  7  5            5
7           7  2  4            5
```

### Note

```
dat <- structure(list(Observation = 1:7, X1 = c(2L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 
7L, 2L), X2 = c(4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 4L), Group = c(1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```